# Read MicroSD card with USB reader while it is connected to (powered-off) microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, usb, avr, spi, sd

I have created a small **breakout** board, where a microSD card is inserted and I can access its signals.

Now, when the necessary SD signals are connected to an AVR microcontroller via SPI, they **communicate successfully**.

**At the same time, I have soldered wires to a** microSD USB adapter, so that the microSD slot pins are now available as wires. When I connect my SD breakout board only with the tweaked USB adapter, **I can successfully read the SD content to my PC**.

The problem emerges when I have the breakout board **connected both** to the AVR and the **tweaked USB adapter** at the same time, even though the AVR is **powered off**. Let me be clear that in order to find the problem I have made sure that there is **no connection** between the SD 3V3 pin and the AVR power supply, to ensure that the AVR does not power on by mistake. As far as the ground of the AVR and that of the SD card, I tried both leaving them connected and isolating them with **no difference**.

As a result, my guess is that there is feedback from the **rest of the SPI signals** that are connected to the AVR, messing with the SD USB reading. Does that sound correct/possible?

If so, I need a way to **isolate** those SPI signals when the AVR turns off, so that I can read my SD card via USB.

I understand the whole procedure sounds weird, but the reason it is needed is that the SD card will be placed in a closed casing where I won't have access. Thus I need the tweaked USB reader to get its stored data via a special connector, when the AVR is off, and I also need the microSD card to be connected to the AVR in order to store data from it, when it is on.

Comment: AVR is powered from SPI lines via internal ESD diodes.

Comment: An alternative to Marku's approach is to place a buffer between the SD card and the micro computer that is inactive when powered off this is probably more complex than Marku's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that AVR, like pretty much all ICs, requires power supply bias voltage for its inputs to behave like inputs. Internally, all of the various integrated transistors are nothing but a bunch of carefully designed P-type and N-type regions. Every PN junction is a diode, whether it is wanted or not. So power supply voltage bias is required to ensure that these so-called "parasitic" PN junctions are reverse-biased so that they do not conduct.

Cutting the power to an IC does not make the input pins behave like they were unconnected.

When voltage is applied to any of the pins of an IC that exceeds the voltage on the power supply pins, those parasitic PN junctions become forward-biased, and current conducts through unwanted paths. This can lead to surprising, erratic behavior. This also happens whenever an unpowered IC gets voltage applied to its input pins.

The best way to work around this issue, is to ensure that your AVR is always powered up when there are signals on its SPI bus. It doesn't have to be running (it can be held in reset), but it must have sufficient voltage on its power supply pins.

One way to address this would be to add Schottky diodes (because of their low forward voltage) between the SPI signals and the positive power supply pin. That way, the Schottky becomes forward-biased before any of the internal parasitic PN junctions.

Another way to address this would be to bring USB power (or lower-voltage power derived from USB) from your microSD adapter, and connect that supply voltage through a Schottky diode to your AVR's power supply. You will also need to add a Schottky diode between the AVR's power supply and its regular power supply, to prevent the USB adapter from trying to drive power into your device's power supply.

Both of these approaches will require some careful handling of the Reset signal. You will need to make sure that the AVR is held in Reset when it is powered by the USB adapter.